# Lookup function for mutate in data

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to store functions, or at least their names, in a column of a `data.frame` for use in a call to `mutate`. A simplified broken example:

```
library(dplyr)
expand.grid(mu = 1:5, sd = c(1, 10), stat = c('mean', 'sd')) %>%
  group_by(mu, sd, stat) %>%
  mutate(sample = get(stat)(rnorm(100, mu, sd))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

If this worked how I thought it would, the value of `sample` would be generated by the function in `.GlobalEnv` corresponding to either `'mean'` or `'sd'`, depending on the row.

The error I get is:

```
 Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
    Evaluation error: invalid first argument.
```

Surely this has to do with non-standard evaluation ... grrr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues here. First `expand.grid` will convert character values to factors. And `get()` doesn't like working with factors (ie `get(factor("mean"))` will give an error). The tidyverse-friendly version is `tidyr::crossing()`. (You could also pass `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to `expand.grid`.)

Secondly, `mutate()` assumes that all functions you call are vectorized, but functions like `get()` are not vectorized, they need to be called one-at-a-time. A safer way rather than doing the group_by here to guarantee one-at-a-time evaluation is to use `rowwise()`.

And finally, your real problem is that you are trying to call `get("sd")` but when you do, `sd` also happens to be a column in your data.frame that is part of the mutate. Thus `get()` will find this `sd` first, and this `sd` is just a number, not a function. You'll need to tell `get()` to pull from the global environment explicitly. Try

```
tidyr::crossing(mu = 1:5, sd = c(1, 10), stat = c('mean', 'sd')) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sample = get(stat, envir = globalenv())(rnorm(100, mu, sd)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Three problems (that I see): (1) `expand.grid` is giving you `factor`s; (2) `get` finds variables, so using `"sd"` as a `stat` is being confused with the column names `"sd"` (that was hard to find!); and (3) this really is a row-wise operation, grouping isn't helping enough. The first is easily fixed with an option, the second can be fixed by using `match.fun` instead of `get`, and the third can be mitigated with `dplyr::rowwise`, `purrr::pmap`, or base R's `mapply`.

This helper function was useful during debugging and can be used to "clean up" the code within `mutate`, but it isn't required (for other than this demonstration). Inline "anonymous" functions will work as well.

```
func <- function(f,m,s) get(f)(rnorm(100,mean=m,sd=s))
```

Several implementation methods:

```
set.seed(0)
expand.grid(mu = 1:5, sd = c(1, 10), stat = c('mean', 'sd'),
            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  %>%
  group_by(mu, sd, stat) %>%              # can also be `rowwise() %>%`
  mutate(
    sample0 = match.fun(stat)(rnorm(100, mu, sd)),
    sample1 = purrr::pmap_dbl(list(stat, mu, sd), ~ match.fun(..1)(rnorm(100, ..2, ..3))),
    sample2 = purrr::pmap_dbl(list(stat, mu, sd), func),
    sample3 = mapply(function(f,m,s) match.fun(f)(rnorm(100,m,s)), stat, mu, sd),
    sample4 = mapply(func, stat, mu, sd)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 20 x 8
#       mu    sd stat  sample0 sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
#    <int> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1     1     1 mean    1.02    1.03    0.896   1.08    0.855
#  2     2     1 mean    1.95    2.07    2.05    1.90    1.92 
#  3     3     1 mean    2.93    3.07    3.03    2.89    3.01 
#  4     4     1 mean    4.01    3.94    4.23    4.05    3.96 
#  5     5     1 mean    5.04    5.11    5.05    5.17    5.19 
#  6     1    10 mean    1.67    1.21    1.30    2.08   -0.641
#  7     2    10 mean    1.82    2.82    2.35    3.65    1.78 
#  8     3    10 mean    1.45    3.10    3.15    4.28    2.58 
#  9     4    10 mean    3.49    6.33    5.11    2.84    3.41 
# 10     5    10 mean    5.33    4.85    4.07    5.58    6.66 
# 11     1     1 sd      0.965   1.04    0.993   0.942   1.08 
# 12     2     1 sd      0.974   0.967   0.981   0.984   1.15 
# 13     3     1 sd      1.12    0.902   1.06    0.977   1.02 
# 14     4     1 sd      0.946   0.928   0.960   1.01    0.992
# 15     5     1 sd      1.06    1.01    0.911   1.11    1.00 
# 16     1    10 sd      9.46    8.95   10.0     8.91    9.60 
# 17     2    10 sd      9.51    9.11   11.5     9.85   10.6  
# 18     3    10 sd      9.77    9.96   11.0     9.09   10.7  
# 19     4    10 sd     10.5     9.84   10.1    10.6     8.89 
# 20     5    10 sd     11.2     8.82   10.4     9.06    9.64
```

`sample0` happens to work because you have grouped it to be row-wise. If at some point any one grouping has two or more values, *this will fail*.

For `sample1` through `sample4`, you can remove the `group_by` and it works equally well (though `sample0` demonstrates its failing, so remove it too). You won't get identical results as above with grouping removed, because the entropy is being consumed differently.